# intent service does not restart after my app crashes

Tags: android, service

So I'm calling my intent service on alarm manager but that intent service does not work after my app get crashed.
Is it possible for intent service to not work after your app get crashed?
Thank You.

Comment: Please, post some code, or Logcat, so we can help you... "crashed" is too generic, could be anything and everything... Also, state how/where you are running the code, and how you are starting and finishing the service.

Comment: Let me clear , are you trying to use intent service inside alarm manager , when ev. alarm  gets fire ? or you are trying to schedule ur alarm manager using Intent service ? and first of all trying to solve ur app crash issue and then check out ur alarm service and etc all ..

Comment: paste some code and the error.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for intent service to not work after your app get
>   crashed?

You shall catch the crash event with an uncaught exception handler and then cancel the alarm something like below,

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        if (myAlarmMgr!= null) {
             myAlarmMgr.cancel(myIntentServiceInstance);
        }
    }
});
```